# How to draw an image by pressing a button in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, graphics, drawing

I have to do this editor (BPMN editor) and I'm stuck.I have this button in the Form with an image on it and I want this: when I click the button and then I press click on my canvas (the draw area) to put the image from the button there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Shape
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

and the code:

```
    private string _currentTool;
    private readonly List<Shape> _shapes;

    private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _currentTool = "img";
    }

    private void PictureBox1MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (_currentTool)
        {
            case "img":
                _shapes.Add(new Shape {Image = button1.Image, X = e.X, Y = e.Y});
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void PictureBox1Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var shape in _shapes)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(shape.Image, shape.X, shape.Y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should never draw using `CreateGraphics`. Whatever you draw onto the `Graphics` object that it returns will not be persistent; that is, it will disappear whenever the window is redrawn. You need to handle the `Paint` event for the `PictureBox` and draw onto the `e.Graphics` object that it provides.

Comment: Navid, you're not disposing of the graphics object. You should be using `using` there.

Comment: @Charlie: As I noted, he shouldn't be using `CreateGraphics`, and the edit corrects this. There's no longer a need to dispose anything.

Comment: Thank you. If I have any other question I'll ask you because I think is a complex project and I'm not so good with the programming.

Comment: Hey again. Now I have to do this: to draw an arc between two images from my canvas, so when I click the button with the arc on it and I put click on one image to paste the arc on it and then to draw the arc as long as i need and to paste it to the second image.

Comment: @Lidia: This is another question, ask it in another post.